# Simple page 301 redirects not working through .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to work out why my `.htaccess` file is not working for a simple page redirect, it's not picking it up. I started with just the bottom two lines but added extra (above) after reading a few posts, but still no luck.

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /shoe-laces-boot-laces-shoestringuk.html https://www.shoestringuk.com/shoe-laces-boot-laces.html
```

Comment: What URL are you going and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: this old page https://www.shoestringuk.com/shoe-laces-boot-laces-shoestringuk needs to re-direct to new page https://www.shoestringuk.com/shoe-laces-boot-laces

Comment: Thats what your `Redirect` already does.  What exactly isn't working for you?